# How to pass jobname info to `latexmk -C`?

Tags: latexmk, makefile, jobname

I created a Makefile which uses `latexmk`.

Example `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Makefile:

```
FILE := FOOO

.PHONY: $(FILE).pdf

all: $(FILE).pdf

$(FILE).pdf: main.tex
    latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex" -jobname="$(FILE)" $<

clean:
    latexmk -c

clean-all:
    latexmk -C
```

The option `-jobname` successfully creates the `$(FILE).pdf` (e.g. `FOOO.pdf`) along with its support files (.log, .fls, .toc, etc).

The problem is that calling `$ make clean-all` does not remove the files generated under this name. How to fix this?¹

¹ I know one option is simply to manually add `rm` for those files. But I'm wondering whether there is an appropriate way to pass `-jobname` info to `latexmk -C`.

---

My fixed Makefile after reading the linked question:

```
FILE := main
OBJ := main

.PHONY: $(FILE).pdf

all: $(FILE).pdf

$(FILE).pdf: $(OBJ).tex
    latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex" -jobname="$(FILE)" $<

clean:
    latexmk -c -jobname="$(FILE)" $(OBJ).tex

clean-all:
    latexmk -C -jobname="$(FILE)" $(OBJ).tex
```

Comment: Duplicate indeed. Was doing `latexmk -C -jobname="$(FILE)"` without passing the `main.tex`. :-\

Comment: Actually, you were calling it without the `-jobname` option, didnt you? That's the actual culprit. Adding the `.tex` does not change anything for me.

Comment: @stefanct  I was. At the time I added `-jobname="$(FILE)" $(OBJ).tex` to `latexmk -C`. I just tried it without the `.tex` and it works as you say.